# Meaning of "get jacked on scag/skag"

Tags: meaning

I heard the following phrase:

> ...get jacked on scag/skag and then get to work.

Source: [Saturday Night Live](http://www.inquisitr.com/3011715/julia-louis-dreyfus-saturday-night-live-skit-heroin-a-m/)

What do "get jacked" and "scag/skag" mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

To *get jacked on scag* is to get high—become intoxicated—on heroin.

Answer (score 1):

The expression jack up is recent and informal, so there is a lot of variation in usage. In the example you quoted, the **up** was omitted. It probably comes from the Scottish slang [jag](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jag), meaning an injection.

[jack up](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jack_up) - informal Inject oneself with an illegal drug.

[scag](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/skag) - heroin